# Jquery remove value from array when deselecting from dropdown

Tags: jquery, arrays, push, splice

I'm trying to remove values from my array when the values are deselected from a multi-select dropdown list. I have the adding of the values working using push() but I'm having some trouble removing when deselected.

Here's what I have:

```
$('#dropdownSelect').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $.each($(this).val(), function(index, value) {
            if ($.inArray(value, myArray) == -1) {
                myArray.push(value);
            } else {
                myArray.splice(index,1);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Second argument to Array.splice() method is how many items to delete. You have 0 there, and it should be 1.

@EDIT

Ok, so you have 1 set.

Another thing is that each time this method is executed you delete all items that are currently selected in `#dropdownSelect` and present in `myArray` from `myArray`. You should be deleting only those that are present in `myArray` and not present in $(`#dropdownSelect`).val().
So you should be doing this in two steps:

1. Iterate against selected values and add to `myArray` those which are not present there,
2. Then iterate against `myArray` and delete those that are not present in selected values in `#dropdownSelect`:

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g2orqhuy/1/
Updated fiddle (removes last object): https://jsfiddle.net/g2orqhuy/2/

Comment: sorry, typo, i have 1 set.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is working. The only thing is there is no way to clear the last value remaining in the array. If I select another value it will replace the the last value, value at index 0.

Comment: I thought this was your intent when I looked at your code, let me fix the fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

please try this one.

```
 $('#dropdownSelect').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val()) {
            $.each($(this).val(), function(index, value) {
                if ($.inArray(value, myArray) == -1) {
                    myArray.push(value);
                } else {
                    myArray.splice($.inArray(value, myArray),1);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```